# Record manual actions and convert them to adb shell am start intents/actions?

Tags: adb, automation, intents

### Question

Is it possible to record phone inputs and the accompanying intents/actions that are executed within an app, and to reproduce them automatically with adb shell?

### Context

I was looking into the output of the:

```
adb shell "dumpsys package | grep -i 'org.torproject.android'"
```

Command, which is:

```
9a8407 org.torproject.android/.OrbotMainActivity
      org.torproject.android.REQUEST_V3_ONION_SERVICE:
        9a8407 org.torproject.android/.OrbotMainActivity
        9a8407 org.torproject.android/.OrbotMainActivity
        da9ed3a org.torproject.android/.core.OnBootReceiver
      org.torproject.android.intent.action.START:
        9f74748 org.torproject.android/.service.StartTorReceiver
        da9ed3a org.torproject.android/.core.OnBootReceiver
        da9ed3a org.torproject.android/.core.OnBootReceiver
        da9ed3a org.torproject.android/.core.OnBootReceiver
        da9ed3a org.torproject.android/.core.OnBootReceiver
        90dcf08 org.torproject.android/.service.OrbotService
  org.torproject.android/.ui.v3onionservice.OnionServiceContentProvider:
    Provider{8d5ddf org.torproject.android/.ui.v3onionservice.OnionServiceContentProvider}
  org.torproject.android/.ui.v3onionservice.clientauth.ClientAuthContentProvider:
    Provider{8dce92e org.torproject.android/.ui.v3onionservice.clientauth.ClientAuthContentProvider}
  [org.torproject.android.ui.v3onionservice.clientauth]:
    Provider{8dce92e org.torproject.android/.ui.v3onionservice.clientauth.ClientAuthContentProvider}
      applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{11b6e8d org.torproject.android}
  [org.torproject.android.ui.v3onionservice]:
    Provider{8d5ddf org.torproject.android/.ui.v3onionservice.OnionServiceContentProvider}
      applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{11b6e8d org.torproject.android}
  [org.torproject.android]
  Package [org.torproject.android] (650fe6a):
    pkg=Package{dfccf5b org.torproject.android}
    codePath=/data/app/org.torproject.android-SQmMOFFMA1-foIkNqQbMDQ==
    resourcePath=/data/app/org.torproject.android-SQmMOFFMA1-foIkNqQbMDQ==
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/data/app/org.torproject.android-SQmMOFFMA1-foIkNqQbMDQ==/lib
    applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{11b6e8d org.torproject.android}
    dataDir=/data/user/0/org.torproject.android
    org.torproject.android/.service.OrbotService: android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE
  [org.torproject.android]
    path: /data/app/org.torproject.android-SQmMOFFMA1-foIkNqQbMDQ==/base.apk
  [org.torproject.android]
```

And I was analysing that to try to find the right command to start an app and press a button inside that app with:

```
adb shell am start -a org.torproject.android.intent.action.START -n org.torproject.android/.service.OrbotService
```

Which returned error:

> Starting: Intent { act=org.torproject.android.intent.action.START cmp=org.torproject.android/.service.OrbotService }

> Error type 3

> Error: Activity class {org.torproject.android/org.torproject.android.service.OrbotService} does not exist.

I assume the syntax is almost correct based on analogue commands in other sources, but that a lack of understanding leads to incorrect commands.
Based on the syntax overlap between the `am start` command, and the `dumpsys` command, I would expect the `adb shell am start` commands can be generated automatically based on a set of intents/actions. I assume it is possible to record the intents/actions that are generated by a user by means of input. Such an automation would save quite some time learning how these intents are specified per app. Hence the question.

The closest I got so far was:

```
adb logcat | fgrep -i intent
```

However, I was not yet able to parse the logs and retrieve the relevant intents from there.

Comment: You need to use `am startservice` to start a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service). `am start` starts [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity).

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve but it will fail immediately if you encounter an activity that is not exported (as you can not start it via adb). And AFAIK button presses are not possible using adb. If you want to automate an app, there are other possibilities like MonkeyRunner (just as a technology example).